# Removing public folder from zend url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have wordpress installed with zend projects included. In wordpress directory I also included my zend project when I check url www.example.com/zend_project/public its working fine but when i included htaccess on root of zend project it displaying 404 wordpress error page. I have removed .htaccess from public to zend root. Any idea how to access withour any wordpress error page. Thanks in advance

My .htaccess contating code is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: How do you plan to recognize which (Zend or Wordpress) should be run?

Comment: i wanted to both run. but the url without public is not working. if i don't write any htaccess then its working fine. http://wordpress.com/zend_project/public. this link is working but not this http://wordpress.com/zend_project/ :( giving wordpress 404 error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave normal Wordpress `.htaccess` file in main directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Add new `.htaccess` in Zend directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/zend_project/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zend_project/public/$1 [L]
```

And leave standard Zend `.htaccess` in your `zend_project/public` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This will redirect all calls to Wordpress, except calls to `/zend_project/*` which will be redirected to Zend.